# Properties with just a getter not serializing to XML

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, xml-serialization, mvccontrib

I have a class (call it pubs) with some members defined as follows

```
public string Publisher { get { return PUBLISHER; } }
public string PublisherUrl { get { return PUBLISHER_URL; } }
public DateTime LastBuildDate { get; set; }
```

Now, an object of this class is serialized and returned as a XMLResult.However, the Publisher and PublisherUrl properties are not part of the XML.

This is being done in the method of my controller which returns an XMLResult (I am using MvcContrib) as follows

```
return XMlResult(pubs)
```

Why would the Publisher and PublisherUrl properties not appear in XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XmlSerializer handles only public properties that have both - a public getter and a public setter